# Creating JSON object and accessing it with PHP CURL returns blank when decoded

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I am trying to create a JSON object from form data and allow access from external server.  if I try and decode it, it returns blank so i imagine im encoding it wrong?

*note the 2 files are on different servers

```
index.php:

//Create JSON Object

  $vx_json->base_value = 5000;
  $vx_json->color_code = 'green';

  echo json_encode($vx_json);
```

Here is the external php file to receive data

```
response.php:

// Get results from index.php

$url = 'mysite.com'
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$response = json_decode($result);
print_r($response);
```

The JSON response is blank unless I do::

```
print_r($result)

{"base_value":5000,"color_code":"green"}
```

But if I do

```
print_r($response);
```

I get no response and cannot access the data like I normally would like this::

```
echo $response['base_value'];
```

What am I doing wrong? am I not encoding it correctly or is the response JSON not decoding correctly?

Comment: good catch, I had that wrong in my example, I fixed it here

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php

Comment: The error function returns '4'

Comment: The function I linked returns a string, not an integer. If you called `json_last_error()`, 4 is `JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX`. The JSON string you have shown is valid, so your actual JSON string must be different.

Comment: Also `green` is not a string literal.

Comment: @gre_gor what do you mean by its not a literal string? In the actual code I pass a variable for these values, I just wrote it out literal for the example.

Comment: "PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant green - assumed 'green'"

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the quotes in the example. I dont have a syntax error in the actual code, I get the result but cant get it when I use json_decode

Answer (score 0):

So I wasn't declaring the $vx_json variable before passing values so it was attempting to create an empty object.

```
$vx_json  = (object)array();
```

Now it works as it should by using

```
echo $response->base_value;
```

Comment: You claimed that you get a JSON string, but parsing failed. How did you expect us to find the problem, if that wasn't the case?

Answer (score -1):

You are echoing on the wrong variable; the json_decode is on $response, not $result. Try this:

```
$response = json_decode($result);
echo $response ['base_value'];
```

Comment: Sorry I had an error in my example, this is what is returning blank, it only returns a response if I echo out the $result before its decoded

Comment: This is strange but, (by the way) is this copying error or your curl url is actually: $ch = curl_init(**$$**url)? Also, maybe your return values are actually not json_encoded at the other side?

Comment: Yeah thats an error from writing the example. I tried to keep it simple instead of just copying over the unnecessary code..